# DNS Server on Fedora 11

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, fedora

I recently upgraded my Fedora 10 server to Fedora 11 and am getting the following error in my DNS/named config.

named[27685]: not insecure resolving 'fedoraproject.org/A/IN: 212.104.130.65#53

This only shows for certain addresses some are resolved fine and I can ping and browse to them fine, while others produce the error above.

This is my named.conf file

```
acl trusted-servers { 192.168.1.10;  };

options {
directory "/var/named";
forwarders {212.104.130.9 ; 212.104.130.65; };
forward only; 

    allow-transfer {
        127.0.0.1;
};
#   dnssec-enable yes;
#   dnssec-validation yes;
#   dnssec-lookaside . trust-anchor dlv.isc.org.;



};




# Forward Zone for hughes.lan domain
zone "funkygoth" IN {
        type master;
        file "funkygoth.zone";
allow-transfer { trusted-servers; };
};

# Reverse Zone for hughes.lan domain
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "1.168.192.zone";
};

include "/etc/named.dnssec.keys";
include "/etc/pki/dnssec-keys/dlv/dlv.isc.org.conf";
include "/etc/pki/dnssec-keys//named.dnssec.keys";
include "/etc/pki/dnssec-keys//dlv/dlv.isc.org.conf";
```

Anyone know what I have set wrong here?

Comment: Just a side note...why using a rolling distro as fedora as a server? Why arent you using a more stable release? Centos? Debian? Ubuntu/LTS? Suse (whats the name of the long support distro...?)

Comment: I only use Fedora because I like it and have used it before, could you recommend an alternative similar distro to use. Probably the subject of a new question.

Comment: There's really no reason not to use Fedora if you're willing to deal with the faster upgrade cycle (which runs into significantly less cruft on a server than a desktop).  The longterm alternative for Fedora is probably CentOS.  CentOS is essentially Red Hat Enterprise Linux with all the branding stripped out and Fedora is the upstream for RHEL.

Comment: I also wouldn't characterize Fedora as a "rolling release", as opposed to something like Gentoo.

Comment: I WOULD CHARACTERIZE FEDROA AS A ROLLING RELEASE. I am using it now, and every two weeks I have a new kernel, every two days I have an updated which recommends rebooting the system, they upgrade major versions in the same release (KDE 4.2 -> KDE 4.3) and more. I just can't use it for 4 weeks without being completely sure that it's the same machine I made. It changed *so* much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a DNSSEC problem but is commented in your config file. You need to check if is enabled for Bind:

```
dnssec-configure -s -b
```

DNSSEC has been included in Fedora 11: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/DNSSEC