# CentOS 7 Firewall Configuration

Tags: centos, firewall, http, https

In CentOS 6 I could type `setup` from the command line and I would be presented with a set of tools, one of them being `Firewall configuration`. I can still do this in CentOS 7, except the list no longer includes `Firewall configuration` as an option.

Does anyone know where I can find it now and why it has been moved?

This is where I used to go to allow incoming traffic via `HTTP` and `HTTPS`. If there's a better way, I'd gladly take the advice. Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation?  [Using Firewalls](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since the release of RedHat/CentOS 7, the previous firewall system has been replaced with **firewalld**.

At the time of writing there is no curses-like console interface similar to system-config-firewall. If you don't mind using a GUI you could use firewall-config instead.

If you need something for the console you will have to use **firewall-cmd** instead.

For more information and full documentation about **firewalld**:
[4.5. Using Firewalls](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html) (or now (subscription required) [How to configure firewalld in RHEL ?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2177831))

I hope this might help you!

Comment: If you want to go back to using `iptables`, see this: http://serverfault.com/questions/470287/how-to-enable-iptables-instead-of-firewalld-services-on-rhel-7-and-fedora-18

Comment: And if you just want to disable the firewall, use: `sudo service firewalld stop; sudo chkconfig firewalld off`

Comment: @DuffJ On RHEL 7 it's `systemctl stop firewalld.service` and `systemctl disable firewalld.service`

Comment: Oh yes! One place where RHEL and CentOS differ. Thanks.

Comment: @DuffJ RHEL 7 and CentOS 7 don't differ in this regard.

Answer (score 18):

Here are some commands with descriptions below that I came across and were helpful

```
firewall-cmd --state
  view status of firewalld service (systemctl status firewalld)
firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
  gets all info for the “public” zone
firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
  shows all info for all zones
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
  adds port 80 to public zone
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent
  adds service http to public zone
firewall-cmd --reload
  run this after making changes
firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=80/tcp --permanent
  to remove port 80 from public zone
firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
  shows default zone for firewall
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
  zones where network interfaces or sources are assigned
```

Answer (score 1):

A quicker way of disabling firewalld is the following.

```
 systemctl disable firewalld
```

this removes the .service so you should get something similar to

> ```
> rm '/etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/firewalld.service'
> rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.service'
> ```

Comment: Doesn't add much to the accepted answer, though.

Comment: You also need to stop firewalld or reboot: :)