# Access denied trying to enable or unmask firewalld

Tags: firewall, centos7, firewalld

My firewall is currently inactive.

```
systemctl status firewalld firewalld.service Loaded: masked (/dev/null) Active: inactive (dead)
```

I used the following command to enable the firewall

```
# systemctl unmask firewalld
```

but I got this error:

```
# systemctl unmask firewalld 
Failed to issue method call: Access denied

# sudo systemctl restart firewalld
Failed to issue method call: Unit firewalld.service failed to load: No such file or directory. 

# sudo systemctl enable firewalld 
Failed to issue method call: Access denied
```

Comment: Is firewalld disabled in favor of iptables.service?  Does `lsmod | grep iptab` show loaded modules?

Comment: This might be a duplicate question - have a look here:
[http://serverfault.com/questions/470287/how-to-enable-iptables-instead-of-firewalld-services-on-rhel-7-and-fedora-18](http://serverfault.com/questions/470287/how-to-enable-iptables-instead-of-firewalld-services-on-rhel-7-and-fedora-18) from that post: "This legacy package provides the systemd scripts for the previous iptables invocation." - in other words, even if firewalld is installed, the systemd config for it might not be.

Answer (score 7):

**solution**

```
sudo systemctl unmask --now firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
sudo systemctl start firewalld
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me.

Check for hanging firewalld proceses, e.g:

```
root  16278  1  4 Jan 13 ?  00:00:00 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
```

kill them and then:

```
# yum reinstall firewalld
# service unmask firewalld
# service enable firewalld
# service start firewalld
```

And of course, look in `journalctl` to see what happened earlier.

Answer (score 3):

This is highly **recommended** that you have a firewall protecting your server:

This error comes when you are trying to start or enable service which is either not installed on your Linux system or you typed an incorrect service name. See list of Services by typing:

```
systemctl list-units --type=service
```

**Install if not available:**

```
yum install firewalld
```

You can **enable firewalld** by typing:

```
systemctl enable firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
```

You can **start firewalld** by typing:

```
systemctl start firewalld
sudo systemctl start firewalld
```

Have a look to check its status by typing:

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

Comment: This is correct. The OP does not have firewalld installed, and needs to install it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for permissions then maybe you can try to

```
sudo su
systemctl enable firewalld
systemctl start firewalld
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to use iptables rather then firewalld as your firewall of choice on centos 7 see [How to enable iptables (instead of firewalld) services on RHEL 7 and Fedora 18?](https://serverfault.com/questions/470287/how-to-enable-iptables-instead-of-firewalld-services-on-rhel-7-and-fedora-18), which includes the exact instructions on how to install and enable iptables for RHEL 7/centos 7.

Comment: What does that link include?

Comment: The exact instructions on how to install and and enable iptables for RHEL 7/centos 7 .

Answer (score 0):

Personally i prefer the old good iptables user space interface. So:

Initially disable firewalld. In your case this may be not necessary:

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```

Then install iptables:

```
yum install iptables-services
```

Enable iptables service:

```
systemctl enable iptables
```

Now you can save your rules as usual:

```
service iptables save
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be following link might be broken

```
/etc/systemd/system/firewalld.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service
```

create it manually by issuing following commands

`ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service /etc/systemd/system/`

Then enable the firewall and start

```
systemctl enable firewalld
```

> [root@localhost ~]# systemctl status firewalld
>   ● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-12-21 00:13:34 GMT; 2s ago
>        Docs: man:firewalld(1)
>    Main PID: 3020 (firewalld)
>      CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
>              └─3020 /usr/bin/python2 -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid