# centos: using epel repository on a server machine

Tags: centos, epel

Are there any downsides in enabling epel repository on a server machine or is it something every sysadmin does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) is reasonably safe and widely used due to its wide selection of useful packages and [careful, enterprise grade quality control](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/GuidelinesAndPolicies). It's virtually required for any EL machine, so much so that I deploy it in all my kickstarts/puppet configs proactively.