# Building Tripwire RPM on CentOS6

Tags: centos6, rpm, tripwire

I have been unable to locate a pre-built RPM for Tripwire on CentOS6.

I have tried installing the one from CentOS5, as well as a couple of later Fedora RPMs, but all fail on a dependency on `libcrypto.so.6`.  I *DO* have the `openssl-devel` package installed (whence `libcrypto.so` but not with the trailing `.6`).

So I tried rpmbuild'ing using the `.spec` file included in the source distribution from SourceForge.

Either I'm doing something way off base (a distinct possibility) or the `.spec` file is way out of date.  To get it to even build I had to tweak several things:

1. Renamed the source directory from `tripwire-2.4.2.2-src` to just
   plain `tripwire-2.4.2.2` because that's what the generated temp script
   seems to expect;
2. Downloaded the required `tripwire-siggen-man8.patch`
   and placed it in `rpmbuild/SOURCES` where the script wants it;
3. created empty `License-Issues` and `tripwire.gif`, also in `rpmbuild/SOURCES`, again because the script needed these files to exist

Now I've hit a roadblock I can't get around.

```
+ cd /home/jhg/rpmbuild/BUILD 
+ cd tripwire-2.4.2.2 
+ /bin/rm -rf /home/jhg/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/tripwire-2.4.2.2-1.el6.x86_64 
+ post
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.tf9QWJ: line 31: post: command not found error: Bad
exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.tf9QWJ (%clean)
```

I *think* the line `post` should be a comment, as the line below it in the script does some post install configuration.

However, with this many tweaks I'm more inclined to believe I went down a wrong path.

Question: Is it possible to build a Tripwire 2.4.2.2 RPM on CentOS6 with the `.spec` file in the source distribution as downloaded, and if so, how is this accomplished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tripwire is in the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository. It's not likely that you have a good reason to even attempt to build it yourself, since [you should already be using EPEL](https://serverfault.com/a/480995/126632).

Comment: I recently switched from Fedora to CentOS due to the dizzying pace of releases and overwhelming new experimental features :-) I was unaware of the EPEL repository. Thanks!

Comment: Haha. I use Fedora for my workstation, since there I can keep up, but CentOS for most of the servers.