# openVPN centOS 6.4 64bit dependency issues

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, dependencies

Everytime I download the openVPN rpm (http://mirror.its.sfu.ca/mirror/CentOS-Third-Party/epel/6/x86_64/openvpn-2.2.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm) and try to install it, I'm running into dependency issues.

What I did:

```
wget http://mirror.its.sfu.ca/mirror/CentOS-Third-Party/epel/6/x86_64/openvpn-2.2.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh openvpn-2.2.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Now everytime I get more and more messages like

```
liblzo2.so.2 is needed by openvpn-2.2.2-1.el6.i686
libpkcs11-helper.so.1 is needed by openvpn-2.2.2-1.el6.i686
```

and more alot of them..

and like

```
glibc = 2.14.90-14 is needed by glibc-common-2.14.90-14.x86_64
```

Then installed it ^..

and then I get this...

```
glibc-common = 2.14.90-14 is needed by glibc-2.14.90-14.x86_64
```

Tired using centOS 5 32bit, and 6.4 32, 64 bit.
Everything is the same, no change.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you randomly grabbed an RPM off the Internet. This is a very bad idea overall.

It appears OpenVPN is in the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository, which [you should already have installed](https://serverfault.com/a/480995/126632). So once you install EPEL on your system, you can just do:

```
yum install openvpn
```

like any other package.

Comment: It says Package not found to me.

Comment: Don't skip any steps next time.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will try this right now & Keep you updated.