# Ansible + why yum not install the latest version

Tags: linux, yum, rhel6, ansible

I am installed successfully the Ansible tool from yum repository as

```
yum install Ansible
```

Ansible is great tool even more then puppet

- From site - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#getting-ansible

but after yum installation I see that the ansible isn't the latest version

```
ansible --version
ansible 1.1
```

- Ansible releases - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases

please advice why yum not install the latest ansible version ( 1.9.X )

Comment: On what Linux distribution?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

Comment: And from what repository did you install ansible?

Comment: I am Just run this command on my Linux machine - yum install ansible  , or maybe I make wrong to do that?

Comment: Ansible is great tool even more then puppet? why?

Comment: I think puppet is much more complicated for use and configuration

Answer (score 5):

I don't know where you got "ansible 1.1". That's certainly not the current version available in RHEL or EPEL repositories.

EPEL 6 currently has ansible 1.9.2, and [you should be using EPEL](https://serverfault.com/q/480994/126632).

```
/srv/www/mirrors/epel/6/x86_64/ansible-1.9.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

[Install the EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) to your system, and then try again.

---

Also remember that [you should not attempt to run RHEL without a subscription](https://serverfault.com/a/537570/126632).

Comment: or maybe because my python version is 2.6.6? - very strange

Comment: so after I installed by yum the ansible 1.1 can I just download the version 1.9 (rpm) and  do upgrade ?

Comment: Hi Hampton please see that --> http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ansible     , ( +1 )

Comment: seems that according to this link the latest version for red-hat is 1.1-2  ( or maybe I missed here something )

Comment: Did you read a single word of this answer?!