# How to install jq on RHEL6.5

Tags: rhel6

There's seems to ready yum package.
So I've downloaded the [tarball](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-1.5.tar.gz), but as soon as I ran `autoreconf -i` , I got the following:

> configure.ac:14: warning: macro `AM_PROG_AR' not found in library
>
> configure.ac:10: error: Autoconf version 2.64 or higher is required
>
> configure.ac:10: the top level
>
> autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 63
>
> aclocal: autom4te failed with exit status: 63
>
> autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 63

So, how can one install jq on RHEL 6.5?

Thank you!

Comment: `Autoconf version 2.64 or higher is required` sounds pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Maybe so, but this is an issue of itself. How can Autoconf be upgraded? This too won't go straightforward fashion...

Comment: Have you considered using one of the ready-made binaries on the jq releases page? https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As it says on the development page for jq "jq is written in C and has no runtime dependencies". So just download the file and put it in place with the following:

```
wget -O jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64
chmod +x ./jq
cp jq /usr/bin
```

Comment: I used the URL provided by for https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ for 64-bit linux. To get wget to work I had to add the `-O jq`. The full command was: `wget -O jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64`

Comment: -O just specifies the output name of the downloaded object. Without specifying it, it should use the name supplied by the URL which in this case is 'jq' so it shouldn't be necessary to add that. I wonder if your version of wget is different somehow in requiring that.

Comment: HTTPS is now supported on github.io => [https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/linux64/jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/linux64/jq)

Comment: Updating link address for v1.5:
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64

Comment: Thx @SaxDaddy Since the new version now has it labeled jq-linux64 I did add the -O jq option so it still has the easy naming.

Comment: Downvoted for using unsigned, pegged version. Should use EPEL.

Comment: @nate EPEL works. But getting the file directly from the source works also, and can ensure you get the latest version if you want. I just updated link to point to version 1.6 which was just recently released

Comment: EPEL for RHEL 6 only has 1.3 available for example.

Comment: @Joe Look at what *just* happened with npm / event-stream to understand why this is still very, very bad.

Answer (score 27):

```
yum install -y epel-release

yum install -y jq
```

Answer (score 17):

`jq` is in the EPEL repository, which you [should already have enabled](https://serverfault.com/q/480994/126632).

Once you have enabled EPEL, you can just `yum install jq` like everything else.

Comment: +1 for not downloading unsigned http stuff.

Comment: The trouble is that the epel one, like everything epel, is out of date if you rely on any of the "newer" features of jq (like the regex support added in jq 1.5 way back in 2015).  The statically linked binary is probably the better way to install it (use something like fpm - https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm - to create an RPM out of it).

Comment: @JonV This is intentional; people who intentionally choose an older distro generally don't want the newer features but would rather have "more stability" instead. In EPEL 7 you will find jq 1.5.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - maybe, however if you're looking for stability, EPEL is _not_ the place to find it.  We were burned recently on a library circular dependency that someone uploaded into EPEL that was not resolveable without explicitly ignoring dependencies.

Comment: @JonV You speak as if that is some sort of regular occurrence that is guaranteed to happen, rather than a bizarre and rare event. It's for such events that we test updates anyway.

Comment: Happens more frequently than I'd like, although I can count them on one hand.  It's the best alternative I know of but I don't think it's great.